# Topo por baixo do menu!

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bem, como podem ver, o topo é um banner preto, no tamanho pra web fica normal, porém quando diminuo, vejo pra testar o responsivo, vejo que o banner está ficando abaixo do menu. A divisão do menu é nessa linha branca, como veem, tá ultrapassando e muito! Como resolvo?

```
            <!-- Começo do logo
            ============================================= -->
            <div id="logo" class="divcenter">
                <a href="index.html" class="standard-logo"><img class="divcenter divtopo" src="images/topo-2.png" alt="banner"></a>
                <a href="index.html" class="retina-logo"><img class="divcenter divtopo" src="images/topo-2@2x.png" alt="banner"></a>
            </div><!-- Fim do Logo-->
```

Comment: Poderias adicionar o código relevante juntamente à tua pergunta?

Comment: Adicionei o código html de inserção do banner.

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta. Qual é que é o problema?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo vejo 2 situações em seu código, melhor dizendo vejo 1 e nela posso definir a seguintes conclusões:

1. **Usando classe css com responsabilidade de entregar conteúdo em diferentes resoluções**;
2. **Não sei como estão os displays  e position de seus containers (banner / menu)**.

Então vamos lá:
Quando quiser entregar imagens diferentes em resoluções x, deixe essa responsabilidade para o navegador (browser), pois ficar difícil prever tal situação, **Progressive Enhancement** na veia Certo!. **Como se faz isso**?

Simples, existe um **novo atributo html** para resolver essa questão é o `srcset="img1, img2..."` inclusive ele recebe um **modificador** como parâmetro para identificar o **device pixel**. Ex:

```
<img src="path-img" alt="desc-img" srcset="img-baixa.jpg 1x, img-alta.jpg 2x">
```

**Obs: Existem outros modificadores além do x(device pixel) vale apena dar uma olhada na documentação da W3C**.

Agora variáveis quanto os container, porque não posso saber ou prever porque não vejo seu código css, então posso afirmar o seguinte:

É natural que o ocorra o empilhamento de container quando ele está com `.myContainer{display:inline;}` ou `.myContainer{float:left;}`

**O que define quem vai vir primeiro ou último**?
Simples, a ordem que você escreveu seu elemento no html, claro existem outras considerações mas aqui prevemos a natureza comum do **DOM** sem **Reflow's**

Baseado nessas informações reveja seu css ou post aqui pra nós! Abs.